Problems with scanf input stream
I am trying to do a postfix evaluation using stack. The output is supposed to be in a format 2,3,4,+,-,# with # signifying the end of expression. The problem is negative numbers are allowed i.e 2,3,-10,+,-,# is also a valid input. I need a method to separate the numbers from the characters.
int main() {
    int num;
    char ch;
    int ret;

    printf("Enter integers or characters separated by commas (e.g., 12,a,34,#):\n");

    while (1) {

        scanf(" ,");

        ret = scanf("%d", &num);

        if (ret == 1) {
            printf("Input is an Integer: %d\n", num);
            if (ret == -1)
                break;
        } else {
            if (scanf(" %c", &ch) == 1) {
                // Print an error message for non-integer input
                //ch = getchar();
                printf("Input is a Character: '%c' (invalid integer)\n", ch);
            } else {
                printf("End of input\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

The problem I am facing is, if the input is 1,2,3,a,b,-1 -> it correctly identifies the numbers as numbers and a,b as characters. But if I give 1,2,3,+,-,#,-1 as input, it somehow takes , instead of + and - while recognizes #. What can I try next?

Side note: I would not consider scanf to be particularly suitable for this use case. Personally, I would use fgets or fgetc (on STDIN) and write code to handle the input from that..

scanf() is generally not the correct function when you don't know what kind of input is coming. You have to tell it whether the item to read is a number or string.

As to your question, note that + and - are valid first characters of an integer input, so are consumed by your scanf("%d", &num) even if it ultimately fails. So you can't successfully use this unless you are prepared to discard singleton + or - and find a way to compensate for the unexpected state this leaves the input steam in. Since this is unacceptable for your use case, you can't successfully use scanf("%d", &num) here.

OT: The code if (ret == -1) can never result in TRUE as it's only executed when if (ret == 1) results in TRUE

OT: I would expect some "special" handling of #

scanf is simply the wrong tool. Read a whole line using fgets and parse the line. For instance you can split the lines into token using strtok with , as delimiter

... and you can then apply sscanf() to the string repeatedly (if you really want that), with various format strings, until one (or more!) variant is acceptable.

Best to think of this as an algorithm problem, not a C problem. Exactly what do you want for input in each case? I suggest something like: state=INT_EXPECTED; while(1) { if (state==INT_EXPECTED) handleInt (); else handleOperator(); readInThatComma; } where handleOperator() ends the loop if it finds a #.

scanf is definitely the wrong tool, but I disagree that fgets is the appropriate replacement.  Perhaps the whole point of post-fix notation is that it is easily implemented using getchar.

comment edit: stdin , not STDIN

This is a state machine problem. While this problem may be simple, more complex problems rapidly become untenable to debug. If your problem scope becomes larger, consider parser generators.

The issue is that the characters + and - may be part of a number, such as in -1, so in the case of these characters, when scanf("%d", &num) fails to read an integer decimal number it will consume the + or - characters from the input, therefore the following scanf(" %c", &ch) ends up reading the separating comma as the input character.
One solution to this would be to first read each entry between commas , as a string and store it in a char array. And to do that you can use the specifier " %[^,\n]" in the scanf function, which is the string specifier to discard leading blank characters, and store anything that is not a comma , or a new line character \n in the char array.
And then you can use the sscanf function to process the string in the array, to find out if it is a valid int or not.
Like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "";
    char ch = '\0';
    int num = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    
    while (scanf(" %99[^,\n]", string) == 1) {
        if (sscanf(string, "%d", &num) == 1) {
            printf("Input is an Integer: %d\n", num);
        }
        else {
            printf("Input is Not an Integer: '%s'\n", string);
            if (strcmp(string, "#") == 0) break;
        }
        ret = scanf("%c", &ch);
        if (ret != 1 || ch == '\n') break;
    }
    printf("End of input\n");
    
    return 0;
}

Or, as suggested by @chux-ReinstateMonica, you could use strtol to process the string, so that you can also handle out of range input values, like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    char string[100] = "";
    char ch = '\0';
    char *end = NULL;
    long num = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    
    while (scanf(" %99[^,\n]", string) == 1) {
        errno = 0;
        num = strtol(string, &end, 10);
        if (string < end && *end == '\0' && errno != ERANGE){
            printf("Input is an Integer: %ld\n", num);
        }
        else if (errno == ERANGE) {
            printf("Input is Out of Range: '%s' (Ranges from %ld to %ld)\n", string, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
            errno = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Input is Not an Integer: '%s'\n", string);
            if (strcmp(string, "#") == 0) break;
        }
        ret = scanf("%c", &ch);
        if (ret != 1 || ch == '\n') break;
    }
    printf("End of input\n");

    return 0;
}


@chux-ReinstateMonica Ok, I've edited the answer and added a solution using strtol.

The problem is scanf("%d", &num) only has one character look ahead. It reads the + sign and since that could start a number, it reads the next character to parse the number, but this character is a , so it pushes it back to the input stream and returns 0.  Your version of scanf cannot push back more than one byte so the next byte read by scanf(" %c", &ch) is the ,, not the + sign.  The same problem occurs for the - after the ,.
This behavior looks like a quality of implementation issue, but the C Standard actually specifies that a prefix of the expected form is read and dicarded, only the first byte that cannot be part of the match is left in the input stream. Hence the + sign and any preceding white space are consumed for the failing %d conversion.  One more pitfall in the scanf family of functions that makes them difficult to use properly and makes error recovery unlikely.
scanf() is not the right tool for your project. fgets and strtol seem more appropriate and provide better error checking:
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[200];

    printf("Enter integers or characters separated by commas (e.g., 12,a,34,#):\n");

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        char *p;
        char *q;
        long num;
        char ch;

        for (p = buf; *p; p++) {
            if (isspace((unsigned char)*p)
                continue;
            errno = 0;
            num = strtol(p, &q, 10);
            if (q > p) {
                if (errno) {
                    printf("Input is an out of bound integer: %.*s\n", (int)(q - p), p);
                } else {
                    printf("Input is an integer: %ld\n", num);
                }
                p = q;
            } else {
                char ch = *p++;
                printf("Input is a character: %c\n", ch);
                if (ch == '#')
                    break;
            }
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*p))
                p++;
            if (*p == ',')
                continue;
            printf("expected a comma\n");
            if (*p == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


@AndreasWenzel: absolutely right :) answer amended.

@AndreasWenzel you are also correct about the specified behavior in case of a prefix. It is unfortunate but a necessary consequence of the limitation to one byte of for pushing back bytes into the input stream. scanf is such a collection of quicks and pitfalls!

Reading user input and parsing is challenging.  Often it is best to separate input from parsing as each have their own particular problems and recovery that do not work well together.
scanf() may not fully restore input that failed a scan.. Only 1 failed scanned character may be restored.  After a failure, scanning again may pick up in unexpected places.

Input, then parse
Consider reading a token: a string up to the delimiter ',', EOF or max length.
char *read_token(size_t n, char token[n]) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  n--;
  size_t i = 0;
  for (;;) {
    int ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if (ch == ',') {
      break;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) {
      if (i == 0) {
        return NULL;
      }
      break;
    }
    if (i >= n) {
      // Token too long
      return NULL;
    }
    token[i++] = (char) ch;
  }
  token[i] = '\0';
  return token;
}

After reading the token, parse it, multiple times, as needed.
#define N 1000
char buffer[N];
while (read_token(N, buffer)) {
  long num;
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  num = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 0);
  if (endptr > buffer && errno == 0 && *endptr == '\0') {
    // We have a valid long.
    ...
    continue;
  }
  
  if ((strlen(buffer) == 1) && (buffer[0] == '-' || buffer[0] == '+'  || ...)) {
    // We have a single character operand.
    continue;
  }

  // look for end
  if (strcmp(buffer, "#") == 0) {
    // We are done
    break;
  }

  // Parsing failed everything.  
  Signal error with TBD code.
}


If obliged to use scanf("%d",..., scan for the sign first.
[ I like the @isnick better - making this wiki]
Something like
while (1) {
  unsigned char sign;
  scanf(" ,");  // TBD, add return value checking to all `scanf()`.
  scanf(" %c", &sign);  
  if (isdigit(sign)) {
    ungetc(sign);
    sign = '+';
  }
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    if (1 == scanf("%d", &num)) {
      if (sign == '-') num = -num;
      printf("Input is an Integer: %d\n", num);
      ...
    } else {
      // sign is the operand + or -
    }
  } else {
    // Test if `sign` is a valid operand + or /, etc.
  }
}

